# How to access guest SD card

Tags: droid-explorer

Using Droid Explorer, how to I access the guest microSD card?

In Windows Explorer, it comes up as a connected device, with a path of `Computer\Acer Iconia Tab A100\SD Card\Documents`

How do I get to that in Droid Explorer?

*(Windows 7 with Android 4.0.3 and Droid Explorer 0.9.0.4)

Answer (score 1):

Oh - you know, this always happens.  I spend time trying to figure things out, and *as soon as* I post a question, I find the answer.  doh!

I found it under `/mnt/external_sd/documents`